# Optaplanner: Evaluate solution

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

I am currently working on a Java project that uses Optaplanner and drools for a Constraint Satisfaction problem.

The solving works fine. But after the [solver](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.0.Beta3/optaplanner-javadoc/org/optaplanner/core/api/solver/Solver.html) has given me a solution, I want to evaluate the solution: I want to know which constraints have been violated, i.e. which rules have been fired and how many times.

Is this possible and how do I start with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See docs section [Reusing the score calculation outside the Solver](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#reusingTheScoreCalculationOutsideTheSolver). That provide all the data you need in a simple way.

```
for (ConstraintMatchTotal constraintMatchTotal : guiScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals()) {
    String constraintName = constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintName();
    Number weightTotal = constraintMatchTotal.getWeightTotalAsNumber();
    for (ConstraintMatch constraintMatch : constraintMatchTotal.getConstraintMatchSet()) {
        List<Object> justificationList = constraintMatch.getJustificationList();
        Number weight = constraintMatch.getWeightAsNumber();
        ...
    }
}
```

See Laune's answer for more advanced drools specific techniques/tricks.

Comment: In the OptaPlanner examples, after solving a dataset, click on the bottom left button "Constraint matches", to see this stuff in action.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the `justificationList` contains the variables that were in the LHS of the rule, when the rule was matched?

Comment: Yes, for 1 matching of the rule.

Comment: Accepted answer, because of the simplicity of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The firing of rules can be observed by implementing an `org.kie.api.event.rule.AgendaEventListener` and attaching it with `KieSession.addEventListener(AgendaEventListener listener)`.

The rule engine is not equipped to explain why some rule has not fired.

It depends on the complexity of the rules you have, but one way is to write rules that evaluate the constraints individually and accumulate a "set of met", after which "all met" can be determined and the complement of an incomplete set is the answer to your question.

Another way is to have rules that fire when one of the patterns or constraints is not met. For instance, in addition to

```
rule abc when A() B() C() then ... end
```

you have to write

```
rule not_a when not A() then ... end
rule a_not_B when A() not B() then ... end
rule ab_not_c when A() B() not C() then ... end
```

This, however, will not tell you *all* missing conditions: if `not_a` fires, also `B` and `C` could be mismatched.